# Get real Build Number from Jenkins API

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-cli

I try to select all current running processes to get the `BuildNumber` an `JobName` of the running pipelines to finaly have the possibility to kill them.
However, if I use the Jenkins API to collect the `BuildNumber` and `JobName` I will get as return:

```
[(master)]:
[org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowJob@6b41187c[myPipeline], org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowJob@6296243a[myDeploy]]
```

I assumed that "*@6296243a[myDeploy]*" is the information I need. But the "*6296243a*" is not a valid `BuildNumber`. I really do not know what this number stands for. Maybe the process id.
The "*myDeploy*" is the `JobName` I need to have.

So my question why I will not get a valid "BuildNumber" here?

```
import jenkins.model.*
import hudson.model.*
  
def result = []
  
  
def buildingJobs = Jenkins.instance.getAllItems(Job.class).findAll { 
  it.isBuilding()
}

println buildingJobs
```

Finaly I want to use the both information at:

```
Jenkins.instance
 .getItemByFullName(<JobName>)
 .getBuildByNumber(<BuldNumber>)
 .finish(hudson.model.Result.ABORTED, new java.io.IOException("Aborting build"));
```

if I use here the values `BuildNumber: 6296243a` `JobName: myDeploy` it will not work. If I use the `BuildNumber` from the view (2357) it works well.

So anybody has a hint how to receive the real `BuildNumber`?

Answer (score 0):

From the example code, you provided, `buildingJobs` will have a List of [WorkflowJob](https://javadoc.jenkins.io/plugin/workflow-job/org/jenkinsci/plugins/workflow/job/WorkflowJob.html) objects. Hence you are getting a reference to the objects when you print it.

Here is how you can get the Build IDs and Job names of currently running and paused builds.

```
Jenkins.instance.getAllItems(Job.class).findAll{it.isBuilding()}.each { job ->
      job.getBuilds().each { b ->        
        if(b.isInProgress()) {
            println "Build: " + b.getNumber() + " of Job: " +  job.getName() + " is Running. Hence Killing!!!"
        } 
   }  
}
```